# ASP.NET MVC2: EF4 + POCO + Repository pattern for beginner?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There are a lot articles introduced these technologies, but looks hard for beginners. Do you know any easy-beginning materials that fit newbies?

Comment: You mean like *I haven't got **any** idea how to do this* or do you mean *I know the basics but have problems with understanding functionality X*? In other words: Are you completely illiterate in any of the technologies you've listed, or do you maybe already know how to use MVC, and EF4 but don't know how to use Repo Pattern etc...

Comment: Start with MVC and ask more specific questions. Move forward to EF4 when you think that you can handle MVC.

Comment: If youre a beginner - then POCO's/Repository/EF4 is probably too complicated. Start with ASP.NET MVC and L2SQL, then move to EF code gen, then move to POCO, then move bang it all together with the Repository pattern.

Comment: And repository pattern usefulness is debatable if your ORM is very capable. Some repository patterns tend to duplicate the functionalities of an ORM http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/17/repository-is-the-new-singleton.aspx

Comment: For MVC, I recommend Steven Sanderson's **Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework** book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) is a great place for beginners to start. It contains many tutorials and videos.